# How to read a file and store in a variable?

Tags: shell-script, text-processing

I am appending data to a file and then use

```
echo "$(tail -n10 newdata.txt)" > newdata.txt;
```

to keep only 10 lines in the `newdata.txt` file.

I want to read this file and store all of its content in a variable so that when I perform

```
{"Value":" "} | jq .
```

to create a JSON file. I will be able to write all 10 values to only one keyword `value`.

I tried

```
value=cat newdata.txt
```

but that is giving me parsing error:

```
Invalid string: control characters from U+0000 through U+001F must be escaped.
```

Comment: Can you elaborate on the `jq` use-case a little more?  Provide examples of your expected input and expected output, if you would.  As it reads now, it seems to sound like a fairly simple case of command substitution.  Your `value=cat newdata.txt` should just be `value=$(cat newdata.txt)` (one way to do it).  Or potentially even just `value=$(tail -n10 newdata.txt)`.  Note -- Since there are linebreaks in the variable, remember to quote it if echo'ing -- E.g. `echo "$value"`.

Comment: I am trying to write a JSON file. For this I am reading values from a board using shell-scripting like ```foo=$(php getdata.php)```, the value of foo is now 11 and then echoing it to the JSON file like ```echo "{\"bar\":\"$foo\"}" | jq . > sample.json
This gives me JSON file like:
{
   "bar": "11"
}
But I want to write multiple values.
Like instead of one value 11, now when I do foo=$(php getdata.php) is 11,12,13,4,12
Then I want to create a JSON like
{
  "bar": "11,12,13,4,12"
}

Comment: Best to edit your question with that info so it can be more readable with line breaks and formatting. Thanks!

Answer (score 2):

This is an [XY Problem](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/66377/what-is-the-xy-problem).  To assign the content of file `newdata.txt` to variable `lines`, use:

```
lines="$(cat newdata.txt)"
```

But why would you want to assign the content of `newdata.txt` to a variable?

Your desired outcome is a JSON object with a field `value` that has the content of `newdata.txt` as its value.  The content of `newdata.txt` is plain text, not JSON, so echoing `{"value", $(cat newdata.txt)}` or equivalently `{"value", $lines}` into `jq .` will not work, because `jq` expects to read valid JSON.

The actual question then is: **how do I turn lines of plain text into JSON?**

`jq` can parse lines of arbitrary input into a stream of JSON strings using option `-R`, `--raw-input`.  To parse all input lines at once, use option `-s`, `--slurp`. The input is then available for regular `jq` stream processing, so:

```
jq -sR '{"value", .}' newdata.txt
```

will give the desired JSON object.

On a separate note, `echo "$(tail -n10 newdata.txt)" > newdata.txt` is bound to fail intermittently.  The `>newdata.txt` has a fair chance of truncating `newdata.txt` to 0 bytes before `tail` gets a chance to read its last 10 lines.  You could use `sponge` to solve this, but see below.

Also, why the `echo`?  `tail -n 10` already echoes to stdout, so there is no need to catch its output in a string, just to have `echo` echo it to stdout again.

Combining all this, a one-line solution would be:

```bsh
tail -n 10 olddata.txt | tee newdata.txt | jq -sR '{"value", .}' && 
mv newdata.txt olddata.txt
```

`bash` has all the facilities of other programming languages, like variables and strings, but it is more productive to think of it as a stream processor that reads from stdin and writes to stdout.

Answer (score 0):

Try:

```
value=$(perl -e 'print qx/cat newdata.txt/;')
```

This uses the "-e" lets you define Perl code to be executed by the compiler.

The $() makes it so you can capture the output of a command and assign it to a shell variable.

Answer (score 0):

I figured it out. I am posting answer for whoever needs it.
I am appending data to a file called newdata.txt like this: `echo "$(tail -n10 newdata.txt)" > newdata.txt;`

Then I simply copied file to a variable called value: value="$(cat newdata.txt)"

After doing `echo "{\"Values\":[$value]}" | jq .` I am getting the JSON object.

The only way this works is there is a comma at the end of each line except for last line.

I am not sure if this is foolproof and right way to do this. But it worked for my problem.